# Problem understanding Rado's proof of the Canonical Ramsey theorem

Tags: combinatorics

I am having trouble understanding the paper with the URL: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/canramsey/Rado.pdf

I get stuck around the middle of page 2 where it says:
f(z0, ..., z_r-1) = f(y0,..., y_r-1)

This assertion doesn't seem to follow from the quantifiers defining L.
I do see that there exists *some* y0, y1,... and *some* y0', y1' , ...

to make the above equality true but that's not enough because here the yi and yi' are arbitrary.

We are given that rho_0 does not belong to L. However, L is defined by a "for all" statement. So, for rho_0, the for-all statement is false and we can find some y set and some y' set which differ only in the rho_0 position to make f(z0, ..., z_r-1) = f(y0,..., y_r-1) true.

But the author is stating something much stronger -- that we can deduce the equality for an arbitrary yi and yi'.

Many thanks for your help.

Paul Epstein

Comment: Either we’re both missing something, or it’s a genuine error.